# .exe file won't run via group policy without explorer.exe

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, group-policy

I have no idea what I am talking about, I'm a programmer not an IT, so please forgive me if my terminology is all confused.
I have two .exe files that I wrote that need to be launched automatically,  via Group Policy. For some reason they will not launch from Group Policy without having explorer.exe. But they will run if explorer.exe is launched first.

I was able to figure out how to kill the explorer.exe process on my computer and I was able to still launch the executables manually. So it's some weird combination of explorer.exe and and Group Policy.

Has anyone seen this before? I'm hoping the solution to this problem is blatantly obvious to someone that knows what they are doing in this space.

Just to clarify. The intent is to not run explorer.exe because it's being used as a Kiosk.

Comment: I usually throw in some delay because it will try to run these as soon as the machine loads.  If `Explorer.exe` is not running yet, it fails.  Try to see about adding something that gives it some time to load startup processes.

Comment: I am under the impression that the client isn't going to be running explorer.exe at all because they have it in Kiosk mode.  Is there a way to make it work without explorer.exe?

Comment: `Explorer.exe` is the main executable that runs the Windows UI, so it should be running regardless.  Regarding workarounds, I cannot say.  Although, its hard to give a definite "Answer" to this cause there are many ways to accomplish it.

Comment: Yeah, they don't want to run the Windows UI, they just want to run google chrome. This will be on the sales floor and they are scared a customer is going to come up and start doing bad things if they have access to the Windows UI.

Comment: If that's the case, just set chrome as the shell, and explorer will not even be started.

Comment: Sorry, the problem isn't that they can't figure out how to keep explorer from starting. The problem is that I can't get these custom executables to run without explorer being run first.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that it is explorer that you're depending on? Not something like the .net framework to be loaded, which happen to load at windows startup too?

Comment: Have you considered using a script on startup that uses a `timeout /t` command for a couple seconds before running your executables?  It is not as clean, but it may do what you are looking for.

Comment: @LPChip I am not absolutely sure. This is just what was reported back to me. It's tricky because I don't have the machine with the symptoms in front of me.

Comment: @CheesusCrust I'll give that a shot. Unfortunately, it might take a while to hear back if it works or not.

Comment: @ChaseRoberts you may want to ask that question to the person who filed it. People often make assumptions based on what they experience, not based on actual facts. Programming languages such as C# require .net framework to run. If the framwork is not loaded, the program will fail to start. Given that the GUI part hasn't loaded, no error will be shown either. It is also possible that the program does start, but that it starts as SYSTEM user, and therefor invisible to the user. In fact, it runs in a different profile, so it does not alter what the logged in user is seeing.

Comment: @ChaseRoberts continue from previous comment: If you want to interact with the session of the logged in user, you will of course need to start the program as the logged in user. There are various places to start programs. Scheduled tasks and registry are 2 different, both with the option to run as system or as logged in user. Only the scheduled tasks can run in the userspace with administrative privileges.

Comment: @ChaseRoberts lastly, and this is likely going to lead to the solution: where exactly in the group policy are you trying to run the executables? Are you choosing startup script (computer configuration) or login script (user configuration), the 1st one obviously runs outside of user space and thus cannot interact with the session of the user, whereas the second one does.

Comment: I don't know if this changes anything, but I wrote the executables in python and then converted them to .exe using pyinstaller. One of the executables listens to a bluetooth dongle that is plugged into the computer, the other executable runs a webserver on port 5000. So if they are running, then they should be able to see something at that web address. I also think that the executables need to be run with admin privileges since they are from an unidentified developer.

Comment: @LPChip My guess is that it is being run on the startup script. But I will have to confirm that as well.